# How do I put a jLabel on top of another using Netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-8

As the title states, how would I approach putting a `jLabel` (which in this case is an image) on top of another `jLabel` (which is also an image)?

The use case is a checkers game. Every time I try to drag another `jLabel` on, it moves the existing one to the side.

[Link to GitHub](https://github.com/shabhshah/Checkers-Game)

[Picture of board so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yOWj.png)

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to look into layered panes - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html